# Materialize jQuery is not working in Rails 6

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm getting error while adding materialize-sass jquery functions in Rails version6

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

//= require jquery
//= require materialize

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {
    $('.sidenav').sidenav();
});
```

**Error:**

```
application.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sidenav is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (application.js:10)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js:4535)
    at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4355)
    at Object../node_modules/turbolinks/dist/turbolinks.js.e.dispatch (turbolinks.js:75)
    at r.notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad (turbolinks.js:994)
    at r.pageLoaded (turbolinks.js:948)
    at turbolinks.js:872
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up sprokets with webpacker

Remove following lines which are syntax of sprokets from the webpacker entry point `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require materialize
```

Assuming you have installed `materialize` using `yarn install` alread, add following line in place of above lines

```js
import 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize'
```

You will also need styles as well. For that create `app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss` file and place following line in it

```
@import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize';
```

now import this `scss` file in your `application.js` using

```
import '../stylesheets/application'
```